# Meteor Color Picker

Tags: javascript, meteor, iron-router

Im trying to get jscolor (http://jscolor.com/) to work on my meteor app.

The jscolor.js javascript file is located at:

```
client/lib/jscolor.js
```

Now when I put an input element with class jscolor in my main.html like:

```
<head>
  <title>Meteor Site</title>
</head>

<body>
   <input class="jscolor" value="ab2567">
</body>
```

it works! But as soon as I put it inside a template which is controlled by the iron router, settings for instance:

```
<template name="settings">
    Settings
     <input class="jscolor" value="ab2567">
</template>
```

It does nothing and it stay a regular input field. Do I need to pass the javascript file to a template somehow or do I need to make it global? Hope someone can help me out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
        meteor add risul:bootstrap-colorpicker
html file
        <template name="hello">
          <input type="text" class="demo1" value="#5367ce" />
        </template>
js file
       Template.hello.rendered = function() {
         $('.demo1').colorpicker();
       }
```